# Do you wash windows, or clean them, or both?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, collocations

my main question is what is the correct verb to precede the noun "windows" to indicate removal of dirt, etc.

The reason I ask is that despite being an English teacher I'm also Dutch, and sometimes I can't tell for certain if something "sounds right" because of my Dutch or because of my English.

I had "to wash the windows" in a test, and a pupil asked if it shouldn't be "to clean the windows". I couldn't explain and really have no idea where to look for these kinds of usages.

Comment: Google Books can help https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=clean+the+windows%2C+wash+the+windows+&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cclean%20the%20windows%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwash%20the%20windows%3B%2Cc0 - anyway note the difference between wash and clean.

Comment: in American English, it is often "do windows"., which, has a simplicity that avoids a lot of other words.

Comment: If you could see what I can see / [when I’m cleaning windows](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/g/george_formby/when_im_cleaning_windows.html).

Answer (score 5):

After reading the other answers/comments, it seems like the preferred verb is a regional thing. J. Taylor commented that it's "do windows" in American English - but, where I've lived in America, I've never heard that phrase. (For what it's worth, it's usually "wash" in the western US.)

Either "wash" or "clean" is valid as a verb here, and, for all intents and purposes, they mean the same thing. So, this might not be the best question for an English test. (;

---

For true window-washing enthusiasts, image searching on US-based Google reveals the most common uses of these phrases:

> "window washer" -> a profession
>
> "window cleaner" -> a cleaning product
>
> "window wiper" -> a squeegee

Answer (score 2):

> I had "to wash the windows" in a test, and a pupil asked if it shouldn't be "to clean the windows". I couldn't explain and really have no idea where to look for these kinds of usages.

Sorry but I think the kid is right :)

I think this is probably the right place to look.  In England we have a profession called "window cleaners".  Therefore clean the windows is used.  We also use "wipe" the windows due to the action of wiping or windscreen wipers.  Wash is usually used in a more encompassing sense.  I wash the dog, I wash the car.  But I don't hose down the windows, I make them clean.  When I shop I look for a window cleaning brush or a squeegee (like a hand held wiper blade).  And yes, oddly, squeegee is used too.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker of American English either sounds fine to me, although there is a subtle difference in meaning: washing implies cleaning **with water**.